# Archive Failed In Jenkins with xcode 10.2

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, xcode10.2

I am trying to build an .ipa from jenkins with freestyle project. I am using xcode10.2 and jenkins ver 2.164.1. 
But I faced the following issue.

**The following build commands failed:**

```
CompileSwift normal arm64
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
```

I tried so many solutions regarding this issue. but none of them help me.

Help from anyone will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too many solutions, I found the perfect solution for this type of issue.

**Just remove the Pods folder and Podfile.lock file** from the project and again install the Pods.

Because swift version is depended on Xcode version. So, as and when we are using updated Xcode with the current project, at that time pods are also needed to be updated.

Currently, I successfully generated .ipa with Xcode 10.2

Comment: I am using Jenkins to create .ipa, after getting a clone from the repo, always use /usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose command than doing code signing process in Jenkins config, but still getting above issue.

Comment: Then delete **Podfile.lock**  and **Pods** folder from your project.  Then install pod again in your project. Build your project. if is there any error solved it and merge it.  Then delete your workspace from jenkins (from user->shared->jenkins->home->workspace) and run jenkins jobs again.